# What is the angle between the extension of a vector and another one intersecting with it?

Tags: geometry, vectors, angle, intersection-theory

Imagine  3 points (p1, p2 and p3) in 2D plane, i have the first vector starts from p1 to p2 and a second vector starts from  p2 to p3. What is the angle between the extension of the first vector and the second vector?[Here is a figure for more illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70AZC.png)

I have solved it in one quadrant, [here is the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xky1T.jpg). But what if the 3rd point is in the second or the third quadrant?

Comment: Can you show your solution and how you got it? It is unclear what you are asking as it is unclear why your solution depends on the quadrant.

Comment: I've modified the question to include my trial

Comment: Use the coordinates of the points to define the vectors $\overrightarrow{p_1p_2}$ and $\overrightarrow{p_2p_3}$. Then just use the dot product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let use that:
$$\cos \theta = \frac{r_1\cdot r_2}{|r_1||r_2|}\implies \theta = \arccos \frac{r_1\cdot r_2}{|r_1||r_2|}$$

with:

- $r_1=p_2-p_1$
- $r_2=p_3-p_2$

Example

[image]

Comment: It did not give me the right answer!!

Comment: @Ahmed can you show your work to check?

Comment: oh sorry, when tried to edit my answer to show you, i found that i have swapped x and y positions, i will try again

Comment: @Ahmed ok, let me know!

Comment: ok, i have tried it for points {(4,5),(5,6),(9,7)}. The result cos(angle) from the above equations equals 0.8574 which equals to 30.963 after solving for angle. But the angle must be 149.036 !

Comment: @Ahmed Could you please give me here the coordinates for $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$, I want to check dorectly by myself

Comment: here is the 3 points that the 2 vectors connect between:              p1=(4,5) , p2=(5,6) , p3=(9,7)

Comment: @Ahmed Ah ok, note that $149.036=180-30.963 $ thus the angle is correct, it depends which one of th etwo you want select, according to the figure it sould be the acute, thus 30.963!

Comment: yes i also noticed that , but this formula i'm going to use in a software code, i.e. there is no figure. So how do i make the right choice and on what basis??

Comment: @Ahmed with reference to your figure here https://i.stack.imgur.com/70AZC.png the angle is acute and the expression I gave are consistent with it

Comment: does this mean that i need a formula for each quadrant??

Comment: @Ahmed No it depends how you choose the vector direction, with my choice $r_1=p_2-p_1$ and $r_2=p_3-p_2$ vector $r_1$ is directed from $p_1$ to $p_2$ and $r_2$ is directed from $p_2$ to $p_3$ thus the angle calculated is the acute one; if we consider $r_1=p_1-p_2$ we would calculate the obtuse one.

Comment: @Ahmed Cosine (via the dot product) has an inherent sign ambiguity—it can’t tell left from right. You can disambiguate by examining $\det(p_2-p_1,p_3-p_2)$, which is proportional to the sign of the angle.

Comment: @amd But if the aim is to evaluate the angle $0\le \theta \le 180°$ and we definie a direction for the two vectors the result by dot product is unique and not ambiguos, or am I wrong?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @amd Then what is exactly your suggestion for $\det(p_2-p_1,p_3-p_2)$ about, sorry but I don't recognize this form

Comment: @Ahmed According to what you’ve written in your question, there’s no choice. You’ve defined one vector to be “from p_1 to p_2,” which is precisely $p_2-p_1$, and the other to be “from p_2 to p_3,” which is precisely $p_3-p_2$.

Comment: If you care about the direction in which the angle is measured (unclear from the question), finding the cosine of the angle isn’t enough. If the rows or columns of $M$ are the vectors $v$ and $w$, then $\det M=\|v\|\|w\|\sin(\angle{vw})$, so its sign lets you tell clockwise from counterclockwise. Indeed, you can use that and the dot product as inputs to an `ATAN2`-style function.

Comment: @amd Ah ok of course, now I've got your point. Thanks

Comment: The following part of the question (But what if the 3rd point is in the second or the third quadrant?)so, how can i get the intersection angle if it was obtuse?

Comment: @Ahmed I've just added one example in the answer. The angle we obtain by the dot product is the angle between the "arrows". Thus it can be acut eor obtuse depending upone the case considered. In the example if we calculate $\theta$ for $F_1=2i+4j$ and $F_2=-5i-3j$ we obtain $180°-32.5$.